# Flink SQL REGEXP_REPLACE Does Not Support Capturing Groups

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Given:

```
 select REGEXP_REPLACE('ERR1,ERR2', '([^,]+)', 'AA$1AA');
```

The result is:
`AA$1AA,AA$1AA`

Is it supported at all (not mentioned in docs) or possible I'm using it incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you expecting as a result ?

Comment: AAERR1AA,AAERR2AA

Answer (score 0):

Flink SQL uses Java's `String.replaceAll` to implement `REGEXP_REPLACE`. It seems like $1 should work, but it doesn't.

I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-34477 to report and track this.

Comment: No. It's $1 and not \1 in Java.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer. Maybe try experimenting with different ways of quoting the $ character?

Comment: I believe it's simply not supported by Flink.

Comment: I did some experiments myself and couldn't get it work either. You could kludge together a workaround using REGEXP_EXTRACT, which does seem to work.

Comment: I agree that this should work, so I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-34477.